# How to smooth shading glitches around edge

Tags: modeling, modifiers

**The red mark** is the mesh beside the groove. How do I make it smooth?
**The green mark** is what I want to make smooth.

[image]

I have used some cutters that are hidden. If you wish you can unhide and see it. I have added subsurf of level 4. Yet the mesh is not smooth some parts.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be scared even more you can use Zebra matcap shading in viewport.
Issue raise more visible.

[image]

You can change *Data Properties > Normals >* **Auto Smooth > Angle to 14** in this case, that make the Normal Shading better, but it doesnt fix it entirely.

[image]

Both issue makes even beter with **SurbSurf 5**.

[image]

... but since cuts are far from folowing base topo, it generates a lot of Ngons with unpredictable triangulation. I think Retopo is waiting for you :)